# kernel of the map $f: E'(K)/\phi(E(K))\to E(K)/2E(K)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry, isogeny

Let $K$ be a number field.
$E/K$ be an elliptic curve over $K$.
Let $\phi : E \to E'$ be an isogeny　of degree 2, that is, $\phi・\hat{\phi}=[2]$. Let $\hat{\phi}$ be dual isogeny of $\phi$.

There is a map $f: E'(K)/\phi(E(K))\to E(K)/2E(K)$.

I want to prove the kernel of $f$ is exactly $E'(K)/\phi(E(K)[2])$.
How can I prove this formally ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The kernel is $E'(K)[\hat\phi]/\phi(E(K)[2])$. $\phi(E(K)[2])$ is $E'(K)[\hat\phi]\cap \phi(E(K))$.

Comment: What role does the dual isogeny play here? Also, are you assuming that the kernel of $\phi$ is contained in the $2$-torsion of $E$?

Comment: @Mathmo123 Thank you very much.$E'(K)/\phi(E(K))/(E'(K)[\hat{\phi}]/\phi(E(K)[2]) \cong E(K)/2E(K)$ should follow, bút how did you come up with that group $(E'(K)[\hat{\phi}]/\phi(E(K)[2])$ ?

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction That first isomorphism doesn't follow: there's no need for $f$ to be surjective.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction the kernel of $E'(K)\to E(K)$ is $E'(K)[\hat\phi])$. Then use one of the isomorphism theorems together with the fact that $E'(K)[\hat\phi]\cap\phi(E(K)) = \phi(E(K)[2])$.

Comment: @Mathmo123. You use something like the following at first ?  'Let $f:A\to D$ be a group homomorphism. Let $B\subset C$ be subgroup of $A,D$ respectively Suppose $g$ induces $f: A/B \to D/C$, then $kerf \cong Kerfg/(kerg \cap B)$' ?

Comment: @Mathmo123 I'm sticking with first step to write down the kernel by quotient of  groups. After that, there is no problem for me.