Basic group theory, Kernel and Coker of $f' : A/B\to C/D$
Let $A,B,C,D$ be abelian groups.
Suppose $B$ is a subgroup of $A$ and $D$ is a subgroup of $C$. Let $f : A \to C$ be a group homomorphism such that $f(B) \subseteq D$. Then $f$ induces a group homomorphism $\tilde{f} : A/B \to C/D$, $x+B \mapsto f(x)+D$.

My question is, what is $\mathrm{Ker}f$ and $\mathrm{Coker}f$ ?

For the $\mathrm{Ker}\tilde{f}$, I don't see the first isomorphism of the following :  $\mathrm{Ker}f' \cong (\mathrm{Ker}f+B)/B\cong \mathrm{Ker}f/(\mathrm{Ker}f \bigcap B)$. The second isomorphism is OK.
For $\mathrm{Coker}\tilde{f}$, if we admit the result for kernel above, then
$\mathrm{Coker}\tilde{f}\cong (C/D)/\tilde{f}(A/B) \cong (C/D)/(A/B)/((\mathrm{Ker}f+B)/B)\cong (C/D)/(A/(\mathrm{Ker}f+B))$.
But I cannot proceed from here.
Thank you for your help.

The definition of $\tilde{f}$ and the assumptions were not meaningful, I have fixed them. Please check if everything looks OK for you.

The image of $\tilde{f}$ is obviously equal to $(D + \mathrm{im}(f))/D$. Hence, the cokernel of $\tilde{f}$ is $(C/D)/((D + \mathrm{im}(f))/D) \cong C/(D + \mathrm{im}(f))$.
The kernel of $\tilde{f}$ consists of those $[a] \in A/B$ such that $[f(a)] = 0$ in $C/D$, i.e. $f(a) \in D$, i.e. $a \in f^{-1}(D)$. Thus, the kernel is $f^{-1}(D) / B$.

If I admit your result for kernel, I think the kernel of this question becomes trivial because ${\phi}^{-1}(2E(K))/\phi(E(K))=\phi(E(K))/\phi(E(K))=0$, but it is not. Where am I missing ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759857/kernel-of-the-map-f-ek-phiek-to-ek-2ek

Also, sorry to ask an elementary thing, but why isn't the image $\mathrm{im}f/D$?

Ask yourself if this quotient makes sense.
